# Reading a C# byte array in Java

Tags: c#, java, tcp, arrays

I'm transferring a file from a C# client to a Java server using TCP Sockets.  On the C# client I convert the file to a byte array for transmission and send it using a NetworkStream.

On the Java server I use the following code to convert the received byte array back into a file;

```
public void run()  {

       try {

            byte[] byteArrayJAR = new byte[filesize];
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                    "Controller " + controllerNumber + ".jar");

            BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            int bytesRead = input.read(byteArrayJAR, 0, byteArrayJAR.length);
            int currentByte = bytesRead;

            System.out.println("BytesRead = " + bytesRead);

            do {

                bytesRead = input.read(
                        byteArrayJAR,
                        currentByte,
                        (byteArrayJAR.length - currentByte));

                if (bytesRead >= 0) {

                    currentByte += bytesRead;

                }
            }

            while (bytesRead > -1);

            output.write(byteArrayJAR, 0, currentByte);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            socket.close();

        }

        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

The code above works if the received byte array comes from a client programmed with Java but for C# clients the code hangs in the do-while loop at the bytesRead = input.read(...) method.

Does anybody know why the code is hanging at this point for a C# client but not a Java client?  According to the output from the println message data is definately being received by the InputStream and is read once at the bytesRead variable initialization, but not during the do-while loop.

Any solutions or suggestions for overcoming this problem would be welcome.

Regards,

Midavi.

Comment: Show us your C# code. Are you perhaps missing a `Flush()`?

Comment: If filesize is not smaller or equal to the data effectively sent, read() will block. You should never try to guess the size of the data you are going to receive, you must keep reading until the stream is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send your bytes as `sbyte` from c# instead of `byte`.

In addition you should change your do/while loop to a regular while loop. If you have already read everything from the stream in your first call to `input.read` then you will block on the second call because `read` will wait for input.

Comment: That shouldn't cause it to hang, but may be a problem at some point.

Comment: until you fix that problem, you aren't going to be able to reliably solve any other problems due to the binary data being wrong.

Comment: A signed byte is the same width as an unsigned byte, therefore, the difference in representation is not going to effect reading from the socket. The OP's *current* problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Based on: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

```
 int bytesRead = input.read(byteArrayJAR, 0, byteArrayJAR.length);
```

Reads all available bytes that means your byte-data is alread in `byteArrayJAR` or am I completly wrong here?

EDIT:

Just checked some of my projects...I send data from Android <=> C# Server Application.

I use `String data = input.readLine();`(java) and `_sw.WriteLine("Testdata");`(C#)

Comment: That is what I believe too.  As far as I'm aware if the file being sent is rather large more bytes may become available after bytesRead is initialized.  The do-while loop is there to make sure the entire byte array is read before being reconstructed into a file.  Or do I have this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot know the amount of data being sent in advance in the general case, it would be better to receive the data in chunks and ignore the offset into your bigger array. Your code as-is doesn't handle the case very well if the data is larger than your array, nor if it is smaller than the array.

A much simpler case would be to remove the `currentByte` offset:

```
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(
    new FileOutputStream("test.exe"));

byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
int bytesRead;
do {
    bytesRead = input.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    System.out.println("size: " + bytes.length + " read(): " + bytesRead);

    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        output.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} while (bytesRead > -1);

output.close();
socket.close();
input.close();
```

And I used the following C# code on the client side:

```
if (!args.Any())
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Usage: send.exe <executable>");
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}

using (var client = new TcpClient("localhost", 10101))
using (var file = File.Open(args.First(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    file.CopyTo(client.GetStream());
}
```

Client side results:

```
C:\temp>csc send.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\temp>send send.exe

C:\temp>
```

Server side results:

```
C:\temp>javac.exe Server.java

C:\temp>java Server
size: 2048 read(): 2048
size: 2048 read(): 2048
size: 2048 read(): 512
size: 2048 read(): -1

C:\temp>test.exe
Usage: send.exe <executable>
```